# Can't set background-color for the body

Tags: css

I'm working on a pretty simple CSS experiment [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/KYw7e/) and I can't seem to set the background color of the body to something different. I'm pulling in the source code of Bootstrap 1.3 before I enter my custom CSS, but it would seem that adding

```
html, body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

would change the background color to black, but it's not. What's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS comments are formated with `/* comment */`.

The comment width which you introduce your custom CSS is wrong (`// BEGIN CUSTOM CSS`). This leads to a false selector which brakes block where you set the `background-color`.

Comment: Nice. That's good to know, I always thought that `//` yielded a comment in CSS, but I guess not. That probably accounts for some of the problems I've dealt with in the past :P

Answer (score 2):

multiple css for same tags is causing the color not to show up

http://jsfiddle.net/KYw7e/16/

Comment: I always thought that CSS rules were simply added to by content later in the document, ie: `body { color: #fff; }` then `body { color: #ccc; background-color: #000; }` would yield `body { color: #ccc; background-color: #000; }` in practice. Is this not so? How can I do this without modifying the Bootstrap source code?

Comment: find the `html,body{background-color:#ffffff;}` in the Bootstrap CSS and comment it out.